# How to find transfer function for the diagram

Tags: transfer-function, homework

I'm studying Control Systems and the teacher gave homework of writing the Transfer Function for given diagram:
[image]

During the class, we solved easier diagrams but with my intuition and experience I came up with a transfer function which looks like this:

[image]

Did I calculate a correct formula?

Comment: Good job for posting an attempt at a solution, most people are too lazy to do that.

Comment: Yes............

Comment: Si.............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the answer I got when I tried to work it out. You even remembered the sign change on the feedback loop. I would say this is correct.

Comment: No need to say thanks, upvote and mark as answered if the answer suits you